# Hinge Loss: what does hinge mean?

Tags: terminology, loss-functions

This is terminology question, I know what is hinge loss mathematically; but I can't grok what *hinge* mean in *hinge loss*. Is it rod, or door hinge, or something else?

Comment: It’s a door hinge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifeze.png

Comment: @AlexR.: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a door hinge, as seen in the shape of the loss function:

[image]

From https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/hinge:

> A hinge is a type of joint that attaches two things together while allowing for limited movement. A door hinge fastens the door to the wall and lets the door swing open.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifeze.png